# sh command is not calling shell script

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, sh

I've written a simple shell script that adds some aliases to a shell it is executed as part of an assignment for school. Here is the contents of the file `testscript.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin

alias dir="ls -l"
alias alerts="cat /etc/motd"
PS1="What next Matt ? "
```

When I use the following command:

```
sh testscript.txt
```

The command appears to run since no errors are returned, however, the alias and command prompt variables have not been changed.

I know that the script works properly because I have tried the following three alternatives, which all worked without a hitch:

```
. ./testscript.txt
. testscript.txt
source testscript.txt
```

The assignment requires that I use the `sh` command. Any suggests to make the command update the aliases and environmental variables?

Here is a screenshot of the assignment so you can see the requirements I must fulfil:
[image]

Thank you for you time and help.

Comment: [you can't control the environment of the parent from a subshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch24_04.htm), which leads me to assume that either (1) `. ./testscript` is just what they're looking for, or (2) you've misunderstood the assignment or (3) they've incorrectly formulated the assignment (which is less rare then you think..). I _would_ add `#!/usr/bin/sh` as the shebang instead of `#!/usr/bin`, that's enough 'sh' in the solution for me..

Comment: @Wrikken: The correct shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, not (necessarily) `#!/usr/bin/sh`. The latter may work on some systems; the former is practically guaranteed.

Comment: @KeithThompson: you are absolutely right, it was just a brainfart here on my part with the obviously out of place `#!/usr/bin`. I stand corrected ;)

Comment: I'm guessing the point of the exercise is to figure out why it doesn't work...? Or maybe just observe that it doesn't, as a platform for further discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Any environment variables you set up inside a stand-alone script will only be visible from within that script. instead, you need to add these commands to `~/.profile` (or whatever its equivalent is on your system). Then they will be executed when you log into the command line console.

Comment: Yes, usually I would set up the environmental variables here or in .bashrc. I posted a screenshot of the assignment so that you're aware of my restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

The shebang (first line) is not correct.

In your case, you should replace the first line by either `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`.

Just search for 'shebang' in Google. It is basically the absolute path of the launched executable.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: -1 While correct and mildly relevant, this is not what the OP is asking about.